Unable to replace python function definition with mock and unitest
I am trying to write integration test for the following python code:
import xx.settings.config as stg
from xx.infrastructure.utils import csvReader, dataframeWriter
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from typing import List
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
import sys


def main(argv: List[str]) -> None:
    args = getResolvedOptions(
        argv,
        ['JOB_NAME', 'S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME', 'S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME', 'S3_BRONZE_PATH', 'S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH'],
    )

    s3_bronze_bucket_name = args['S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME']
    s3_pre_silver_bucket_name = args['S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME']
    s3_bronze_path = args['S3_BRONZE_PATH']
    s3_pre_silver_path = args['S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH']

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() 
    spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')


    for table in list(stg.data_schema.keys()):
        raw_data = stg.data_schema[table].columns.to_dict()
        df = csvReader(spark, s3_bronze_bucket_name, s3_bronze_path, table, schema, '\t')
        dataframeWriter(df, s3_pre_silver_bucket_name, s3_pre_silver_path, table, stg.data_schema[table].partitionKey)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)

I basically loop on a list of tables then read their content (csv format) from S3 and write them in parquet format in S3 also.
These are definitions of csvReader and dataframeWriter:
def csvReader(spark: SparkSession, bucket: str, path: str, table: str, schema: StructType, sep: str) -> DataFrame:
    return (
        spark.read.format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('sep', sep)
        .schema(schema)
        .load(f's3a://{bucket}/{path}/{table}.csv')
    )



def dataframeWriter(df: DataFrame, bucket: str, path: str, table: str, partition_key: str) -> None:
    df.write.partitionBy(partition_key).mode('overwrite').parquet(f's3a://{bucket}/{path}/{table}/')

For my integration tests I would like to replace S3 interaction with
local files interaction (read css from local and write parquet in local. This is what I done:
import os
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
import xx.application.perfmarket_pre_silver as perfmarket_pre_silver
from dvr_config_utils.config import initialize_settings


def local_csvReader(spark: SparkSession, table: str, schema: StructType, sep: str):
    """Mocked function that replaces real csvReader. this one reads from local rather than S3."""
    return (
        spark.read.format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('sep', sep)
        .schema(schema)
        .load(f'../input_mock/{table}.csv')
    )


def local_dataframeWriter(df, table: str, partition_key: str):
    """Mocked function that replaces real dataframeWriter. this one writes in local rather than S3."""
    output_dir = f'../output_mock/{table}/'
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    df.write.partitionBy(partition_key).mode('overwrite').parquet(output_dir)


class TestPerfmarketSilver(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('TestPerfmarketSilver').getOrCreate()
        cls.spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        """Clean up the Spark session and test data."""
        cls.spark.stop()
        os.system('rm -rf ../output_mock')

    @patch('xx.application.cc.getResolvedOptions')
    @patch('src.xx.infrastructure.utils.csvReader', side_effect=local_csvReader)
    @patch('xx.infrastructure.utils.dataframeWriter', side_effect=local_dataframeWriter)
    def test_main(self, mock_csvreader, mock_datawriter, mocked_get_resolved_options: Mock):

        expected_results = {'chemins': {'nbRows': 8}}


        mocked_get_resolved_options.return_value = {
            'JOB_NAME': 'perfmarket_pre_silver_test',
            'S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME': 'test_bronze',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME': 'test_pre_silver',
            'S3_BRONZE_PATH': '../input_mock',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH': '../output_mock'
        }
        perfmarket_pre_silver.main([])

        for table in stg.data_schema.keys():
            # Verify that the output Parquet file is created
            output_path = f'../output_mock/{table}/'
            self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(output_path))

            # Read the written Parquet file and check the data
            written_df = self.spark.read.parquet(output_path)
            self.assertEqual(written_df.count(), expected_results[table]['nbRows'])  # Check row count
            self.assertTrue(
                [
                    column_data['bronze_name']
                    for table in stg.data_schema.values()
                    for column_data in table['columns'].values()
                ]
                == written_df.columns
            )

What I wanted to do with these two lines:
@patch('src.xx.infrastructure.utils.csvReader', side_effect=local_csvReader)
@patch('xx.infrastructure.utils.dataframeWriter', side_effect=local_dataframeWriter)

Is to replace definitions of csvReader by local_csvReader and dataframeWriter by local_dataframeWriter.
Unfortunately, code is retuning
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

This is my project structure:
project/
│
├── src/
│   └── xx/
│       ├── application/
│       │   └── perfmarket_pre_silver.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── infrastructure/
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── utils.py
│       └── other_modules/
└── tests/
    └── integration_tests/
        └── application/
            └── test_perfmarket_pre_silver.py

Both csvReader and dataframeWriter are defined in utils.py.
Error is pointing to csvReader call in main code (first snippet).
So my replacing technique is clearly not working.
What am I doing wrong please ?

You passed schema in the csvReader call, but not defined in the function.

It is defined. I removed non necessary details. Problème is I do not want to execute csvReader but its 'replacement'/'mock' local_csvReader

Could you add please the path of the file where is defined main()? For completeness add also the path of the file where are defined csvReader and dataframeWriter.

@User051209 I just updated my question

@Haha sorry but I can't understand the error message and I have an other doubt: in the file test_perfmarket_pre_silver.py how can the code access to stg.data_schema.keys if there isn't any import of stg and any definition of it in that file? With your current code I can't simulate your code in my system, please edit your question once again to help me understand the problem.

@User051209 I reformulated my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79102700/is-my-integration-test-well-structured-and-why-is-it-returning-import-error

I am sorry that my detailed explanation of why mocking s3a was needless -and if you did want to emulate an s3 store then there were tools to do it. please accept my apologies for providing the two recommendations that actually run your code (file://) urls, or emulate S3 closely enough for the s3a codebase to work.

replace the s3a:// URL with file:// URLS and spark will just read/write to your local filesystem.
Trying to emulate S3 semantics is a really complex piece of work and I would seriously advise against it. If you do have to follow that path, either deploy minio locally or try out Adobe's S3 mock: https://github.com/adobe/S3Mock . It has all the S3 operations the S3A connector supports. At least I thin so...we only test the s3a code against real S3 endpoints: S3 standard, S3 express, google gcs (!) and some third party stores. marginally slower but way better at finding regressions and quirks.
