Is my integration test well structured and why is it returning import error
I am learning mock and trying it on a personal project.
This is my project structure:
project/
│
├── src/
│   └── My_app/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── application/
│       │   └── main_code.py
│       │   └── __init__.py
│       ├── infrastructure/
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── data_quality.py
│       │   └── s3_utils.py
│       └── settings/
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── s3_utils.py
│
└── tests/
    └── integration_tests/
        └── application/
            └── test_main_code.py

Aim is to write integration test for main_code.py
simplified version of main_code.py
import My_app.settings.config as stg
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from My_app.infrastructure.data_quality import evaluateDataQuality, generateSchema
from My_app.infrastructure.s3_utils import csvReader, dataframeWriter
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def main(argv: List[str]) -> None:
    args = getResolvedOptions(
        argv,
        [
            'JOB_NAME',
            'S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME',
            'S3_BRONZE_PATH',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH',
            'S3_DATA_QUALITY_LOGS_BUCKET_NAME',
        ],
    )

    s3_bronze_bucket_name = args['S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME']
    s3_pre_silver_bucket_name = args['S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME']
    s3_bronze_path = args['S3_BRONZE_PATH']
    s3_pre_silver_path = args['S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH']
    s3_data_quality_logs_bucket_name = args['S3_DATA_QUALITY_LOGS_BUCKET_NAME']

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()  # TODO replace this init with common method (waiting for S3 part)
    spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')


    for table in list(stg.data_schema.keys()):
        raw_data = stg.data_schema[table].columns.to_dict()

        schema = generateSchema(raw_data)
        df = csvReader(spark, s3_bronze_bucket_name, s3_bronze_path, table, schema, '\t')


        (quality_df, table_ingestion_status) = evaluateDataQuality(spark, df, table)

        dataframeWriter(
            quality_df,
            s3_data_quality_logs_bucket_name,
            'data-quality/',
            'logs',
            'date',
            'append',
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)

simplified version of data_quality.py
import My_app.settings.config as stg
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsgluedq.transforms import EvaluateDataQuality
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType, StringType, FloatType, DateType


def typeOf(t: str) -> IntegerType | StringType | FloatType | DateType:
    ...
    return StringType()


def generateSchema(columns_dict: dict) -> StructType:
    ...
    return schema


def evaluateDataQuality(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame, table: str) -> (DataFrame, bool):
    ...
    return (
        EvaluateDataQuality.apply(...)
        .toDF(),
        True,
    )

simplified version of s3_utils.py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType


def csvReader(spark: SparkSession, bucket: str, path: str, table: str, schema: StructType, sep: str) -> DataFrame:
    """Reads a CSV file as a Dataframe from S3 using user parameters for format."""
    return (
        spark.read.format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('sep', sep)
        .schema(schema)
        .load(f's3a://{bucket}/{path}/{table}.csv')
    )


def dataframeWriter(
    df: DataFrame, bucket: str, path: str, table: str, partition_key: str, mode: str = 'overwrite'
) -> None:
    """Writes a dataframe in S3 in parquet format using user parameters to define path and partition key."""
    df.write.partitionBy(partition_key).mode(mode).parquet(f's3a://{bucket}/{path}/{table}/')

What I want to do
Write an integration test for main_code.py while:

Mocking csvReader function and replace it with local_csvReader.
Mocking dataframeWriter function and replace it with local_dataframeWriter.
Mocking the import from awsgluedq in order to avoid installing it locally.

What I did:
test_main_code.py
"""Module that contains unit tests for My_app pre silver job."""

import os
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType


def local_csvReader(spark: SparkSession, bu: str, pa: str, table: str, schema: StructType, sep: str):
    """Mocked function that replaces real csvReader. this one reads from local rather than S3."""
    return (
        spark.read.format('csv')
        .option('header', 'true')
        .option('sep', ';')
        .schema(schema)
        .load(f'./tests/integration_tests/input_mock/{table}.csv')
    )


def local_dataframeWriter(df, bu: str, pa: str, table: str, partition_key: str):
    """Mocked function that replaces real dataframeWriter. this one writes in local rather than S3."""
    output_dir = f'./tests/integration_tests/output_mock/{table}/'
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    df.write.partitionBy(partition_key).mode('overwrite').parquet(output_dir)


class IntegrationTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('TestPerfmarketSilver').getOrCreate()
        cls.spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')

    @patch('My_app.application.main_code.getResolvedOptions')
    @patch('My_app.application.main_code.csvReader', side_effect=local_csvReader)
    @patch('My_app.application.main_code.dataframeWriter', side_effect=local_dataframeWriter)
    def test_main(self, mock_csvreader, mock_datawriter, mocked_get_resolved_options: Mock):
        """Test the main function with local CSV and Parquet output."""
        import My_app.application.main_code as main_code

        import My_app.settings.config as stg
        import tests.integration_tests.settings.config as stg_new

        stg.data_schema = stg_new.data_schema_test

        expected_results = {'chemins': {'nbRows': 8}}

        # Mock the resolved options
        mocked_get_resolved_options.return_value = {
            'JOB_NAME': 'test_job',
            'S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME': 'test_bronze',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME': 'test_pre_silver',
            'S3_BRONZE_PATH': './tests/integration_tests/input_mock',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH': './tests/integration_tests/output_mock',
            'S3_DATA_QUALITY_LOGS_BUCKET_NAME': 'test_dq',
        }

        main_code.main([])

        for table in stg.data_schema.keys():
            # Verify that the output Parquet file is created
            output_path = f'./tests/integration_tests/output_mock/{table}/'
            self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(output_path))

            # Read the written Parquet file and check the data
            written_df = self.spark.read.parquet(output_path)
            self.assertEqual(written_df.count(), expected_results[table]['nbRows'])  # Check row count
            self.assertTrue(
                set(
                    [column_data['bronze_name'] for column_data in stg.data_schema[table]['columns'].to_dict().values()]
                )
                == set(written_df.columns)
            )
            # Clean up
            os.system(f'rm -rf ./tests/integration_tests/output_mock/{table}/')

Questions:
Running test class is returning:
======================================================================
ERROR: test_main (tests.integration_tests.application.test_main_code.IntegrationTest)
Test the main function with local CSV and Parquet output.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1248, in _dot_lookup
    return getattr(thing, comp)
AttributeError: module 'My_app.application' has no attribute 'main_code'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1376, in patched
    with self.decoration_helper(patched,
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1358, in decoration_helper
    arg = exit_stack.enter_context(patching)
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 492, in enter_context
    result = _cm_type.__enter__(cm)
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1431, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1618, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1261, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/Users/me/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/unittest/mock.py", line 1250, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
  File "/Users/me/IdeaProjects/project_root/apps/project/src/My_app/application/main_code.py", line 10, in <module>
    from My_app.infrastructure.data_quality import evaluateDataQuality, generateSchema
  File "/Users/me/IdeaProjects/project_root/apps/project/src/My_app/infrastructure/data_quality.py", line 4, in <module>
    from awsgluedq.transforms import EvaluateDataQuality
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsgluedq'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2.114s

FAILED (errors=1)


Is my test class well structured ? I am importing main_code right ?
I dont think so because of:     AttributeError: module 'My_app.application' has no attribute 'main_code'

How can I integrate a mocking technique to replace awsgluedq module by another code ?



I think there are some mistakes in your code, so to help us to create a valid answer, you have to solve some of these. Start with one: there isn't any file called config in the package My_app/settings. Do you mean s3_utils instead config. This problem is into all your files where you insert following import instruction import My_app.settings.config

You can solve your problem following the suggestions present in this answer. In particular see the try, except around the import. This is sufficient to solve the problem of the module awsglue. Sorry but your code is very difficult to reproduce so I'm not able to write a complete answer. Try with the link and give me a feedback.

What you should do is to mock the GlueContext the same way you mocked the getResolvedOptions method with @patch('My_app.application.main_code.getResolvedOptions').
Example: @patch('My_app.application. data_quality. GlueContext', side_effect=lambda: True) or any other side effect that make sense for you!

It is because does not make sense to mock an import, because you use a mock to simulate (or mock) a behavior of some object. The import per se (most of the time) does not make anything alone.

Take a look at this answer to see if it helps

Firstly, include comments in your code. It was very difficult to read and make sense of.
Secondly, for the 'awsgluedq' package you will need to import 'runpy' on Line 1 for mainly python.
Third, 'main_code' is not defined because it is not for the package. Instead you will want to use the expression between these square brackets; [name == 'main'].
NOTE: For name You will need to import 'configparsner' on an early line.
And if you need to access the main .py file. You will need to use this expression 'main.py file' for python packages.
Parts of this were sourced by some other users who assisted with this. If this is incorrect, I would ask a genuine professional.
But other than that, aside from some minor adjustments. Your mock code is well structured.

Thank you dor your answer. Can you please provide some code ?

#Here's the edited code that I copied and edited. Sorry for the wait, took #quite some time to debug and test:
import My_app.settings.config as stg
#Make sure to import runpy
import runpy
_name_ == _main_.py
from _main_.file import awsglue
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from My_app.infrastructure.data_quality import evaluateDataQuality, generateSchema
from My_app.infrastructure.s3_utils import csvReader, dataframeWriter
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def main(argv: List[str]) -> None:
    args = getResolvedOptions(
        argv,
        [
            'JOB_NAME',
            'S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME',
            'S3_BRONZE_PATH',
            'S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH',
            'S3_DATA_QUALITY_LOGS_BUCKET_NAME',
        ],
    )

    s3_bronze_bucket_name = args['S3_BRONZE_BUCKET_NAME']
    s3_pre_silver_bucket_name = args['S3_PRE_SILVER_BUCKET_NAME']
    s3_bronze_path = args['S3_BRONZE_PATH']
    s3_pre_silver_path = args['S3_PRE_SILVER_PATH']
    s3_data_quality_logs_bucket_name = args['S3_DATA_QUALITY_LOGS_BUCKET_NAME']

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()  # TODO replace this init with common method (waiting for S3 part)
    spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')


    for table in list(stg.data_schema.keys()):
        raw_data = stg.data_schema[table].columns.to_dict()

        schema = generateSchema(raw_data)
        df = csvReader(spark, s3_bronze_bucket_name, s3_bronze_path, table, Schema, '\t')


        (quality_df, table_ingestion_status) = evaluateDataQuality(spark, df, table)

        dataframeWriter(
            quality_df,
            s3_data_quality_logs_bucket_name,
            'data-quality/',
            'logs',
            'date',
            'append',
        )

#You made a mistake here:
#Your name and main had two underscores instead of one.
#You also missed the import from main.file for 'awsglue' make sure to include that
if _name_ == '_main_':
    main(sys.argv)

import My_app.settings.config as stg
_name_.py == _main_.py
from _main_.file awsglue.context import GlueContext
from _main_.file awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from _main_.file awsgluedq.transforms import EvaluateDataQuality
from _main_.file pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from _main_.file pyspark.sql import functions as F
from _main_.file pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from _main_.file pyspark.sql.types import StructType, IntegerType, StringType, FloatType, DateType


def typeOf(t: str) -> IntegerType | StringType | FloatType | DateType:
    ...
    return StringType()


def generateSchema(columns_dict: dict) -> StructType:
    ...
    return schema


def evaluateDataQuality(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame, table: str) -> (DataFrame, bool):
    ...
    return (
        EvaluateDataQuality.apply(...)
        .toDF(),
        True,
    )

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

#This is the CSVReader code, what you wrote did not read or write properly. So here it is.
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

dynamicFrame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://s3path"]},
    format="csv",
    format_options={
        "withHeader": True,
        # "optimizePerformance": True,
    },
)

dataFrame = spark.read\
    .format("csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .load("s3://s3path")

Write CSV to S3
For show, customize how to write string type values. Set quoteChar to -1 so our values are not quoted.
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=dynamicFrame,
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://s3path"},
    format="csv",
    format_options={
        "quoteChar": -1,
    },
)

dataFrame.write\
    .format("csv")\
    .option("quote", None)\
    .mode("append")\
    .save("s3://s3path")

glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = datasource1,
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://s3path"]}, 
    format = "csv", 
    format_options={
        "optimizePerformance": True, 
        "separator": ","
        }, 
    transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

